# Parsing XML file using Go

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I'm new on Go. I have a task to do where I have a xml file with the following structure. There many other tag record in this file.

I need to read all the records, and print the information about the Kind of music but only where datafield tag is equal "650" and the subfield code tag = "a".

```
<record>
  <leader>01153cjm a22002771a 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">   00000838 </controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="003">DLC</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20030506181700.0</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="007">sd|zsngnnmmned</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">000824s1998    nyuppn                  d</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="050" ind1="0" ind2="0">
    <subfield code="a">SDA 16949</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="010" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">   00000838 </subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="020" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="c">$15.98</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="024" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">601215312621</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="0">
    <subfield code="a">Rap (Music)</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
```

My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Record struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"record"`
    Text         string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Leader       string   `xml:"leader"`
    Controlfield []struct {
        Text string `xml:",chardata"`
        Tag  string `xml:"tag,attr"`
    } `xml:"controlfield"`
    Datafield []struct {
        Text     string `xml:",chardata"`
        Tag      string `xml:"tag,attr"`
        Ind1     string `xml:"ind1,attr"`
        Ind2     string `xml:"ind2,attr"`
        Subfield []struct {
            Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            Code string `xml:"code,attr"`
        } `xml:"subfield"`
    } `xml:"datafield"`
}

func main() {

    xmlFile, err := os.Open("music_lite3.xml")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened music_lite3.xml")

    defer xmlFile.Close()

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var record Record

    xml.Unmarshal(data, &record)

    for j := 0; j < len(record.Controlfield); j++ {
        for i := 0; i < len(record.Datafield); i++ {
            if record.Datafield == "650" {
                if record.Datafield.Subfield.Code == "a" {
                    fmt.Println("Kind of Music: " + record.Datafield.Subfield.Text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having problems to acess the structs datafield and subfield. 
It seems that when a call record.Datafield and record.Datafield.Subfield.Code 
Go is not recognizing the structs.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

=)

Comment: It might help if you check the error from unmarshal. Then, you can printf the record (or use a debugger), and see what's in it.

Comment: "Go is not recognizing the structs" meaning what exactly? What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even compile. You need to index the slices inside the loops, you can't refer to fields of elements of slices without indexing them. Also `Record.Controlfield` and `Record.Datafield` are not "related", it's senseless to process them with embedded loops.

However, you do need to use nested loops to check `Subfield` of a `Datafield` whose tag matches.

Something like this:

```
for i := range record.Datafield {
    df := &record.Datafield[i]
    if df.Tag == "650" {
        for j := range df.Subfield {
            if df.Subfield[j].Code == "a" {
                fmt.Println("Kind of Music: " + df.Subfield[j].Text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HJci3jO9T94).

Note that you could use `for range` to also "get" the element at the given index, but since you have some kind of generated struct which uses anonymous structs (and not pointers), such a loop would copy all elements (hence I stayed with "manual indexing").

Also do check all errors, e.g. `ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)` and `xml.Unmarshal(data, &record)`.